# Passing a string variable to labs in ggplot2 not being accepted

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
seed=1234
df=data.frame(rnorm(50)*100)
names(df)="Temperature"; df
nn = length(df$Temperature)
title = "Daily Temperature"
title2 = substitute(paste(title,"(",degree,"C)"))
title3 = paste(title,"\n(n = ",nn,")")
h1 = ggplot(df, aes(x=df[,1]))+ geom_density(colour = "black", fill = "white", binwidth = 5)
+    labs(list(title = title3, x = title2, y = "Counts"))
h1
```

Above mini example describes my problem with displaying "title2" on the x-axis. I've searched and tried many good suggestions (e.g., aes_string, expression, etc...) but still can't get this to work. If I replace title2 with; `title2 = expression(paste("Daily Temperature (",degree,"C)"))`, it works fine. Thanks in advance for your help! Vince

Comment: Your variable `title2` is not a `character` string.  see `class(title2)`.  What is wrong with your second option using `expression`?

Comment: Thanks Justin! I have many versions of plot "h1" and want to be able to change the x-axis title via a variable. Is there a way to change the "title2" class to "string" to make this work?

Comment: Thanks for the edit to the questions Ananda!

Comment: @Justin: Changing to:  `title2 = expression(paste(title,"(",degree,"C)")); changes the question to how to pass an "expression". Problem still persists. Vince

Comment: The way you're using `degree` requires this `expression` syntax within  ggplot.  Why doesn't that version meet your needs?

Comment: @Justin: My plan was to write a single "plot" function and pass the variable "title" along with the "df" for many different cases. A work around would be to write separate functions for each different title. Not my preferred option...and not a satisfactory soln. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require(ggplot2)  # not everyone has this package loaded by default
seed=1234
df=data.frame(rnorm(50)*100)
names(df)="Temperature"; df
nn = length(df$Temperature)
title = "Daily Temperature"
```

To do this cleanly requires plotmath experience. See ?plotmath and ?substitute. I find that using plotmath `paste` is usually not needed if you use `*` and `~`.

```
  # first argument to substitute is an expression object
  # you need to supply a list as the second argument to substitute 
title2 = substitute(title*"("*degree*C*")", list(title=title) )
title3 = paste(title,"\n(n = ",nn,")")
h1 = ggplot(df, aes(x=df[,1]))+ 
  geom_density(colour = "black", fill = "white", binwidth = 5) + 
  labs(list(title = title3, x = title2, y = "Counts"))
h1
```

[image]

The other way to have parentheses in a plotmath expression is to use the plotmath `list` function (which is different that the ordinary list function in that it creates comma separated expressions.) With only one expression it just give the parentheses:

```
title2 = substitute(title*list(degree*C), list(title=title) )
```

Comment: Great and thanks!! Saved me a lot of work and frustation. p.s. Nice alias:)